# asp.net Inline feedback "Alert/Confirmation/Error" after form submission. (Success!)

Tags: asp.net, webforms, feedback

I am seeking to implement a simple alert in asp.net that informs a user the submission was successful. I am new to asp.net and would appreciate some guidance. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Alert box can be called using the following function from your code behind.

```
 void mbox(string msg)
 {

      ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "", "alert('" + msg + "');", true);
 }
```